# Background version of uploaded video creation in Elixir with Arc and FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, elixir, automatic-ref-counting

I tried to make video uploading on Elixir phoenix project using Arc. I need to have different size versions of video. So I used FFmpeg to do this:

```
def transform(:large, {file, scope}) do
  {:ffmpeg, fn(input, output) -> "-i #{input} -c:a copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 #{output}" end, :mp4}
end
```

However, it takes a lot of time to create this versions even to small videos. So, I decided to make version creation on background. I want Arc to upload video, then I give the response with uploaded original while other versions are creating.

I was hoping to find such option at https://github.com/stavro/arc but I didn't succed. I only found "To disable asynchronous processing, add @async false to your upload definition" but I don't want to disable it, right?

I tried to use Exq https://github.com/akira/exq for background processing but I didn't menage to use it in uploader.

Could anybody tell me how it should be made in a proper way or give me some dirty hack advice to make it work. Thanks.

I tried Task as was advised in comments, but I am not sure how to use them in this case. When I try

```
{:ffmpeg, fn(input, output) -> Task.async(fn -> "-i #{input} -c:a copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 #{output}" end) end, :mp4}
```

or

```
{:ffmpeg, Task.async(fn -> fn(input, output) ->  "-i #{input} -c:a copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 #{output}" end end), :mp4}
```

I got "protocol String.Chars not implemented for %Task".

When I try

```
{:ffmpeg, Task.async(fn(input, output) ->  "-i #{input} -c:a copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 #{output}" end), :mp4}
```

I got "#Function<20.83953603/2 in MyWebSite.Content.transform/2> with arity 2 called with no arguments". I tried to pass function as an argument with "&" but it fails as well.

My uploader:

```
defmodule MyWebSite.Content do
use Arc.Definition
use Arc.Ecto.Definition

@acl :public_read

@versions [:original,  :huge]

def transform(:huge, {file, scope}) do
  {:ffmpeg, Task.async(fn(input, output) ->  "-i #{input} -c:a copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 #{output}" end), :mp4}
end

def s3_object_headers(version, {file, scope}) do
  [timeout: 3_000_00, content_type: Plug.MIME.path(file.file_name)]
end
end
```

Comment: Spawn a [`Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async/1) doing this?

Comment: Either process asynchronously  as @mudasobwa is alluding to or either consider a service, such as: https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

Comment: @mudasobwa, KevinJohnson thanks for help, but I failed to use Task. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? I have edited the question.

Comment: Please show us where you _call_ `transform`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I have edited question with my uploader file. Versions are created when file is uploading. Is there is any way to call transform not at that moment?

Answer (score 0):

From the `Arc`’s README (section [Complex Transformations](https://github.com/stavro/arc#complex-transformations)):

> However, the transformation may be done completely outside of `Arc`. For fine-grained transformations, **you should create an executable wrapper** in your `$PATH` (eg. bash script) which takes these proper arguments, runs your transformation, and then moves the file into the correct location**.

That said, if you want the transformation to be run completely asynchronously, just create a bash script somewhere and call it like (assuming it’s name is `myffmpeg`):

```
def transform(:huge, {file, scope}) do
  {:myffmpeg,
     fn ->
       "-i #{input} -c:a copy -s 1920x1080 -f mp4 #{output}"
     end,
   :mp4}
end
```

The script should *spawn* `ffmpeg` passing the arguments and move the result to the folder `Arc` wants.